# How do I delete an entity from the Minecraft world folder?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Basically, I acidentally spawned too many ArmorStands due to a wrong code writing , resulting in the game crashing, and wanted to know how to delete those armorstands from the World save folder. They hava names and I belive they also have a scoreboard set, if that helps.

I have already tried to open the world but it crashes, I tried to open a server (Since it worked the last time I tried it) and killing it all from the console but, different from the last time, it crashed before killing them and now I just tried MCedit but it crashes as well.

Comment: The starting point could for example be the program "NBTExplorer", but I don't know how you would efficiently delete all entities of a certain type within a certain region using that program.

Comment: I did just find NBTExplorer and I'm exploring it. It appears that it shows every loaded chunk with every thing stored in it. Now all it rests for me is to find the chunk... That said, If I can really delete it, I will have solved my problem. Thanks anyways.

Comment: It worked! I'll post an answer whenever I get home

Comment: Deleting the chunks if of course an option, yes. I thought about just removing the armour stands.

Comment: Oh no, I'm talking about removing entities From a chunk. Minceraft stores info in an interesting Wat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple solution: [NBTExplorer](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding-java-edition/minecraft-tools/1262665-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac)

Our problem is: Too many armorstands causing the game to overload and none of the three listed options working. Thus, removing these entities would fix our problem.

After [installing](https://www.wikihow.com/Use-NBTexplorer-to-Edit-Minecraft-Saves) the program, open it and select your world save folder. The file/folder we are looking for is "region"; it contains all chunks and a lot of information stored in it

[image]

Now, all you need to do is know the chunk coordinates (they are different from World coordinates) and mine happend to be in spawn chunks."Chunk [0, 0] in world at (0, 0)"

In this same picture we can see the "Entities: 21845". They are the bad boys!

Upon opening it, we can see all of the entities!

[image]

And clicking in one of these "folders", they show us valueable informations, such as the type, tag and even their custom names!

[image][image]

Now, there is two things we gotta do to delete all of them:

First, copy the precious ones to another place, it can be anywhere.

[image]

it's important to copy them since you cannot cut more then on per time. To select them all, just press shift and left click... yeah, it's the only way... Luckly I had to copy 10 only.

After that, delete the 21k entries 'entities' folder and copy your backup/precious ones back there. Remember to also delete the old backup folder.

Lastly, save it. It will not auto save if you close it.

If by any means your tab looks like this:(Pic bellow)

Just re-open it. It's normal to crash if there are that many entities.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

you can try reducing your view distance to 2 chunks and if it loads the world do the command (it should kill all the armor stands)
/kill @e[type=ArmorStand]
if it doesn't work please reply and I will try to help :D

Comment: As I tought, I did not work since I'm way too close to these ArmorStands.